# Quintessential models for dark energy

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

Following [Sean Carroll](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Carroll/Carroll2.html) here

> There are good reasons to consider dynamical dark energy as an alternative to an honest cosmological constant. First, a dynamical energy density can be evolving slowly to zero, allowing for a solution to the cosmological constant problem which makes the ultimate vacuum energy vanish exactly.

Does this mean that vacuum fluctuations from the electroweak and strong nuclear forces will vanish also?

Comment: Vacuum energy and vacuum fluctuations are two different things.

Comment: vacuum fluctuations contribute to vacuum energy